# Python Recursive Turtle Tree with Random Length

Tags: python, recursion, random, tree

I am having trouble incorporating the random function into my Recursive Tree function.

The Random should take the length given in drawTree and add/subtract a range of 0 - length//2.

I have the random line at the beginning of the function but it does not change my graphic at all.

```
def drawTree(length, generations):
    length = random.randint(-length//2,length//2)
    if generations == 0:
        pass
    else: 
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.left(45)
        drawTree(length/2, generations -1)
        turtle.right(90)
        drawTree(length/2, generations -1)
        turtle.left(45)
        turtle.backward(length)
```

My `drawScene()` function works properly

Is the random line not in the right place?

Comment: what if `random.randint` is 0?

Comment: ...what you are doing is, if your lenght is 4, setting the lengt to a random number inbetween -2 and 2. I don't think you want your turtle to walk backwards, do you?
Correct would be: `lenght += random.randint(-lenght//2, lenght//2)`
About your main problem: I don't know what's wrong, it seems right... are you sure you use the right function name and not a dublica?

Comment: turned out I needed to name it as a new variable